# Jest returns undefined when testing a function that get the html attributes from elements

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have this function I want to test in jest :

```js
getAttributes(el) {
    let dataAttrs = {};
    let attributes = el.attributes;
    const dataAttributes: any = Object.values(attributes);

    for (const dataAttribute of dataAttributes) {
      let keyName = dataAttribute.name;
      let keyValue = dataAttribute.value;
      dataAttrs[keyName] = keyValue;
    }

    return dataAttrs;
}
```

Here is my jest test:

```js
test('get attributes on element', () => {
  let breadcrumb = new DsBreadcrumb();
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.ca/');
  element.innerHTML = 'lorem ipsum lorem ispum';

  console.log(element.innerText);

  expect(breadcrumb.getAttributes(element)).toBe('Hello');
});
```

This is what jest returns :

[image]

I know my code works outside of jest and when I console log the dataAttributes I get this : 
[image]

So in my code when I do : 
let keyName = dataAttribute.name;

keyname returns undefined because it cannot find the value of the a html element. In the photo above you can see the info I need, but for some reason it isn't a MockAttr object under _name

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export class DsBreadcrumb {
  public getAttributes(el) {
    const dataAttrs = {};
    const attributes = el.attributes;
    const dataAttributes: any = Object.values(attributes);

    for (const dataAttribute of dataAttributes) {
      const keyName = dataAttribute.name;
      const keyValue = dataAttribute.value;
      dataAttrs[keyName] = keyValue;
    }

    return dataAttrs;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { DsBreadcrumb } from './';

describe('59867716', () => {
  describe('#getAttributes', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      const breadcrumb = new DsBreadcrumb();
      const mEvent = { attributes: { a: { name: 'a name', value: 'a value' } } };
      const actual = breadcrumb.getAttributes(mEvent);
      expect(actual).toEqual({ 'a name': 'a value' });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59867716/index.test.ts (13.135s)
  59867716
    #getAttributes
      ✓ should pass (6ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.124s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59867716

Comment: wow ok thanks this works perfectly. I had two questions :

Why did you put on describe under another?

Why does jest return mockAttr, any reason for this?

Comment: 1. multiple `describe` are some kind of hierarchical categories, you can treat them as some kind of folder structure of your PC system. It's clear when you have a lot of test suites and test cases. 2. The return value is got by executing the `getAttributes` method, If you change the logic, the result can be changed. It's not arbitrary. `mEvent` is input => `getAttributes` => got `{ 'a name': 'a value' }` output